# Instantiating XAML UIElement using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make something on my windows phone, I have been googling "Instantiating UIElement in C#", but I can't seem to find anything that can help me..

What I want to do is this :-

1) User press a button

2) My program will instantiate a new Grid/Stackpanel with some Textblock in it.

Is there a link for me I could refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add a `Click` event to your button.

```
<Button Click="DoSomethingAmazing" .../>
```

And in your C# code behind, you can then create your `Grid`, and add a `TextBlock`.

```
private void DoSomethingAmazing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grd = new Grid();

        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Wow!"
        };

        grd.Children.Add(txt);

        //Add your grid to the window/page/usercontrol
        this.AddChild(grd);
    }
```

The code to add the child to the parent may differ depending on what platform you are on, but I think you get the idea.

That being said, you shouldn't be instantiating controls in your code-behind, instead, you should declare them in XAML, and in your case at least, use `Visibility` to show/hide the controls.

XAML is there for a reason, embrace it.

Comment: That's good news, if this has answered your question, you should mark this answer as accepted :-)

Comment: You can click on the tick on the left hand side of the answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Name your container:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and then in the event handler write e.g.:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Children.Add(grid);

        }
```